# Shell POSIX OpenSSL file decryption script

Tags: linux, aes, sh, posix, openssl

Tonight, I tried to write a Bash OpenSSL file decryption script. Encryption script will follow in highly similar manner, so I think it's not necessary now.

Let's suppose we have an encrypted large file using:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in somefile -out somefile.enc
```

You correctly noticed I always add `.enc` to the file name.

---

The meaning of the script is:

- take one, and only one, argument as a file
- ask user for password
- decrypt that file with `openssl` with a shown progress
- save it without the `.enc` extension, or if it didn't have that extension, give it `.dec` extension
- not to overwrite existing files

---

Though I wrote it with maximum effort, a review is more than welcome.

The script follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ] || [ ! -f "$1" ]
then
    echo "A single existing file needs to be given as an argument. Exiting."
else
    input_filename="$1"
    filepath=$(dirname "$1")
    filename_extracted_from_path=$(basename "$1")
    filename_without_enc_extension="${filename_extracted_from_path%.enc}"

    if [[ "$filename_extracted_from_path" == "$filename_without_enc_extension" ]]
    then
        output_filename="$filepath/$filename_extracted_from_path".dec
    else
        output_filename="$filepath/$filename_without_enc_extension"
    fi

    if [ -f "$output_filename" ]
    then
        echo "Destination file exists. Exiting."
    else
        pv "$input_filename" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -salt -out "$output_filename"
    fi
fi
```

---

**EDIT1:**

- I decided to put the script on GitHub (when done), therefore it must be POSIX compliant, so I have made minor changes.
- I found out, the script lacks destination directory writable check, so I integrated it.
- Also, it now checks if it is run as `root` (or with `sudo`).

But the structure remains and new version of the script follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ] || [ ! -f "$1" ]
then
    echo "A single existing file needs to be given as an argument. Exiting."
else
    input_filename="$1"
    filepath=$(dirname "$1")
    filename_extracted_from_path=$(basename "$1")
    filename_without_enc_extension="${filename_extracted_from_path%.enc}"

    if [ "$filename_extracted_from_path" = "$filename_without_enc_extension" ]
    then
        output_filename="$filepath/$filename_extracted_from_path".dec
    else
        output_filename="$filepath/$filename_without_enc_extension"
    fi

    if [ -f "$output_filename" ]
    then
        echo "Destination file exists. Exiting."
    else
        if [ ! -w "$filepath" ] && [ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]
        then
            echo "Destination directory is not writable. Exiting."
        else
            pv --wait "$input_filename" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -salt -out "$output_filename"
        fi
    fi
fi
```

---

Uploaded on GitHub: https://git.io/fxslm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Get rid of unnecessary nested and combined `if`s

While here it goes to no extreme, it's advisable to check for errors first, and to do that one by one - if possible, which is exactly this case.

### Do some extra checks

- Only in case of 0 arguments, the script should output usage message.
- This script does not support multiple arguments, so if given more than 1, inform the user.
- The script only checks for existence of the file, but what if it's not readable by the user.

### Use `tput` for handling text colors instead of escape sequences

Those escape sequences are non-portable and the fact it works in `dash` does not mean it would do the job in Cygwin for instance; `tput` is clearly more portable.

```
bold=$(tput bold)
red=$(tput setaf 1)
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
nocolor=$(tput sgr0)

bold_red=${bold}${red}
bold_yellow=${bold}${yellow}
```

### Write a function for handling errors

```
print_error_and_exit()
{
    echo "${bold_red}$1 Exit code = $2.${nocolor}"
    exit "$2"
}
```

### Shorten test commands, since there are only `if` ... `then`

```
[ "$#" -eq 0 ] \
&& print_error_and_exit "One argument needs to be given. Both relative, and absolute file paths are supported." 1
```

### Declare and initialize variables just before they're used

The following declarations:

> ```
> input_filename="$1"
> filepath=$(dirname "$1")
> filename_extracted_from_path=$(basename "$1")
> filename_without_enc_extension="${filename_extracted_from_path%.enc}"
> ```

Should be split in order not to declare / initialize variables the script may not use in event of a failure.

### Use `exit` return codes

The script should give the system feedback for example for automated processing. And be sure to use different `exit` codes in every failure event.

### Root account check is unnecessary

The following test:

> ```
> [ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]
> ```

Does not serve the intended purpose and should be omitted.

### Comment code, that is not self-explanatory

The following code:

> ```
> if [ "$filename_extracted_from_path" = "$filename_without_enc_extension" ]
> then
>     output_filename="$filepath/$filename_extracted_from_path".dec
> else
>     output_filename="$filepath/$filename_without_enc_extension"
> fi
> ```

May be a little unclear, so a short comment is advisable.

### The script should give feedback to the user too

The core code:

> ```
> pv --wait "$input_filename" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -salt -out "$output_filename"
> ```

Should say something like:

> ```
> Decryption failed / successful.
> ```

### Clean after failed decryption

In the event of failed decryption, there is an empty output file present.

### (Optional) The decryption status message could use some colors

In the end, if the decryption fails, it shows something similar to:

> ```
> bad decrypt
> 140673166227096:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:529:
> ```

Though it might suffice to say the above mentioned message, some users might prefer it in color.

---

### Based on the above code, I would re-write it as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

bold=$(tput bold)
red=$(tput setaf 1)
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
nocolor=$(tput sgr0)

bold_red=${bold}${red}
bold_yellow=${bold}${yellow}

print_error_and_exit()
{
    echo "${bold_red}$1 Exit code = $2.${nocolor}"
    exit "$2"
}

[ "$#" -eq 0 ] \
&& print_error_and_exit "One argument needs to be given. Both relative, and absolute file paths are supported." 1

[ "$#" -gt 1 ] \
&& print_error_and_exit "Multiple arguments are not supported." 2

[ ! -f "$1" ] \
&& print_error_and_exit "The given argument is not an existing file." 3

input_filename="$1"

[ ! -r "$input_filename" ] \
&& print_error_and_exit "Input file is not readable by you." 4

input_filepath=$(dirname "$input_filename")

[ ! -w "$input_filepath" ] \
&& print_error_and_exit "Destination directory is not writable by you." 5

filename_extracted_from_path=$(basename "$input_filename")
filename_without_enc_extension="${filename_extracted_from_path%.enc}"

if [ "$filename_extracted_from_path" = "$filename_without_enc_extension" ]
then
    # the file has a different than .enc extension or no extension at all
    # what we do now, is that we append .dec extention to the file name
    output_filename="$input_filepath/$filename_extracted_from_path".dec
else
    # the file has the .enc extension
    # what we do now, is that we use the file name without .enc extension
    output_filename="$input_filepath/$filename_without_enc_extension"
fi

[ -f "$output_filename" ] \
&& print_error_and_exit "Destination file exists." 6

if ! pv -W "$input_filename" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -salt -out "$output_filename" -d 2> /dev/null
then
    [ -f "$output_filename" ] && rm "$output_filename"

    print_error_and_exit "Decryption failed." 7
else
    echo "${bold_yellow}Decryption successful.${nocolor}"

    exit 0
fi
```