# Portable (Linux, Cygwin,...) Makefile for my own Shell OpenSSL file en-/decryption scripts

Tags: beginner, linux, portability, makefile, installer

Let it be clear that in this question I ask for further guidance with my current version of `Makefile` used for my own [Shell OpenSSL file en-/decryption scripts](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/182381/104270), not those scripts themselves.

I did my best, but this is my own first `Makefile`, so I better give it to you for review. I may only *think* the work is done, there may be many issues I don't know about.

Requirements:

- The implicit destination path must be easily overridden without having to edit the `Makefile`
- The implicit target must check for integrity (hashsum) stored in the file `SHA512SUMS`
- The file must account for non-standard Linux environments like Cygwin
- I myself tested it under normal circumstances in Linux Mint 18.3 and Cygwin
- All files can be simply acquired from [GitHub page of this little project](https://github.com/burianvlastimil/openssl-file-encryption-decryption-shell-scripts)

---

The `Makefile` follows:

```
DESTDIR?=/usr/local/bin
install_path=$(DESTDIR)

script_name_1=encrypt-file-aes256
script_name_2=decrypt-file-aes256

user_id=$(shell whoami)
group_id=$(shell id -gn)

.PHONY: check
.PHONY: install
.PHONY: uninstall

check:
    [ -f $(script_name_1) ] && [ -f $(script_name_2) ] && sha512sum --check SHA512SUMS --status && echo "OK: Files are prepared. You may use make install command now." || echo "ERROR: Files are missing and / or hashsum mismatch!"

install:
    install --verbose --mode=0755 --owner=$(user_id) --group=$(group_id) --target-directory=$(install_path) $(script_name_1) $(script_name_2)

uninstall:
    rm $(install_path)/$(script_name_1) $(install_path)/$(script_name_2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `check` target always succeeds (because the last command in the pipeline is `echo`).  We'd like it to fail if any of the tests fail, so we should just write them one per line.  Instead of testing for the existence of the files, we should make the `check` target *depend* on them:

```
check: $(script_name_1)  $(script_name_2)
    sha512sum --check SHA512SUMS
    @echo "OK: Files are prepared. You may use make install command now."
```

BTW, `script_name_1` and `script_name_2` are completely unhelpful variable names.  How about `encrypt` and `decrypt`, for example?

---

I think the `install` target should depend on `check` - we really don't want to install if the check fails:

```
install: check
```

---

I'm not convinced that this is a good thing:

```
user_id=$(shell whoami)
group_id=$(shell id -gn)
```

When we install software, we normally make it owned by an appropriate user on the system, not the person doing the installing.  In most cases, programs are owned by `root`, so that no ordinary user can accidentally overwrite them (or any other harmful action).

---

Make provides a `$(RM)` definition to give you a more portable command for deleting files.

---

It's great that you've thought about install location and about overridability of such parameters.  You probably ought to know the conventional variables that are used for these:

- **`DESTDIR`** specifies where the root directory is.  This is usually empty, but packaging tools set this to a suitable working directory to build a (partial) filesystem image that can be archived.
- **`PREFIX`** works somewhat like your `DESTDIR` or `install_path` (I'm not sure why you have two names for the same thing).

---

This is a rare Makefile that doesn't need `.DELETE_ON_ERROR:` (since it contains no non-PHONY targets).

---

## Modified code

This is what I ended up with:

```
PREFIX = /usr/local

install_path = $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/bin

encrypt = encrypt-file-aes256
decrypt = decrypt-file-aes256

check: $(encrypt)  $(decrypt)
    sha512sum --check SHA512SUMS
    @echo "OK: Files are prepared. You may use make install command now."

install: check
    install --d -D $(install_path)
    install -m 0755 -t $(install_path) $(encrypt) $(decrypt)

uninstall:
    $(RM) $(install_path)/$(encrypt) $(install_path)/$(decrypt)


.PHONY: check install uninstall
```

Note that Make variables specified on the command line will override those in the Makefile, so you can write

```sh
make install PREFIX="$(HOME)/testing"
```

to install to your test directory, for example.

Answer (score 0):

### Write the `check` target's commands with lines in between

You can easily enhance the user experience by:

Inserting a blank line in between the command itself and its output.

---

### Write a `distrib` target to automatically make a package for further distribution

If you ever intend to distribute this code, it has to be easily packageable, so it should:

- Remove possibly, not necessarily existing package files.
- Create some distribution directory.
- Compute the `SHA512SUMS` file.
- Copy only what is necessary - the scripts and the `Makefile`.
- The rest (`LICENSE` and `README.md`) may change and should be downloaded directly from GitHub.
- On Cygwin for instance, all created files on the NTFS file system are marked executable. Thus, you should ensure proper permissions are in place.
- `tar` the directory with your favorite compression method.
- And finally, delete the temporary directory.

---

### [Toby Speight](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/75307/toby-speight) has [pointed out a few things](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/205391/104270) I adopted and enhanced in some cases

> Instead of testing for the existence of the files, we should make the `check` target depend on them.

- I also added `SHA512SUMS` file, which is needed too.

> `script_name_1` and `script_name_2` are completely unhelpful variable names.

- I agree, renamed to `encrypt_script` and `decrypt_script`.

> The `install` target should depend on `check`.

- I agree, dependency added.

> I'm not convinced that this is a good thing: `user_id` and `group_id`.

- After testing in Cygwin and Linux Mint, it seems these are unnecessary. Commented out, just in case, someone will provide a reason to use it.

> `DESTDIR` specifies where the root directory is... + `PREFIX` works somewhat like your `DESTDIR`...

- After reading some articles, it seems you are right, code changed.

---

### Things I changed myself for a reason

- Those `.PHONY`s seem to be possible to declate in one line.
- Target `uninstall` tries to remove the directory also in case it is empty.
- And a few nice touches.

---

### Enhanced re-write based on the above information

```
PREFIX?=/usr/local/bin
install_path=$(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)

encrypt_script=encrypt-file-aes256
decrypt_script=decrypt-file-aes256
distrib_name=openssl-file-encryption-decryption-shell-scripts

#user_id=$(shell id --name --user)
#group_id=$(shell id --name --group)

.PHONY: check install uninstall distrib

check: $(encrypt_script) $(decrypt_script) SHA512SUMS
    echo && sha512sum --check --status SHA512SUMS && ( echo "Ok. You may use 'sudo make install' or '(sudo) make install PREFIX=SomeDir' command now." ) || ( echo "ERROR: Files hash sum mismatch!" && echo && exit 1 )

install: check
    echo && [ -d $(install_path) ] || mkdir --parents $(install_path)
    install --verbose --mode=0755 --target-directory=$(install_path) $(encrypt_script) $(decrypt_script) # --owner=$(user_id) --group=$(group_id)

uninstall:
    rm $(install_path)/$(encrypt_script) $(install_path)/$(decrypt_script)
    rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty $(install_path)

distrib: $(encrypt_script) $(decrypt_script) Makefile
    rm --force $(distrib_name).tar.xz
    rm --force --recursive $(distrib_name)
    mkdir $(distrib_name)
    sha512sum $(encrypt_script) $(decrypt_script) > $(distrib_name)/SHA512SUMS
    cp $(encrypt_script) $(decrypt_script) Makefile $(distrib_name)
    wget --quiet --output-document=$(distrib_name)/LICENSE https://raw.githubusercontent.com/burianvlastimil/openssl-file-encryption-decryption-shell-scripts/master/LICENSE
    wget --quiet --output-document=$(distrib_name)/README.md https://raw.githubusercontent.com/burianvlastimil/openssl-file-encryption-decryption-shell-scripts/master/README.md
    chmod 755 $(distrib_name)/$(encrypt_script) $(distrib_name)/$(decrypt_script)
    chmod 644 $(distrib_name)/Makefile $(distrib_name)/SHA512SUMS $(distrib_name)/LICENSE $(distrib_name)/README.md
    tar --create --xz --file=$(distrib_name).tar.xz $(distrib_name)/*
    rm --force --recursive $(distrib_name)
```